# How to convert Angular/Typescript string with date format of 'M/d/yyyy' to Java Date format?

Tags: angular, spring

I'm getting an error of

```
"TypeError: params.title.split is not a function"
```

When my date field pass to the rest-api is in the form of `'11/30/2019'('M/d/yyyy')`, however when I changed the format into `"2019-11-30T16:00:00.000+0000" (ISO format)`, it works fine.

I'm using Reactive forms in **Angular** and the data we're pass through `formarray`

Comment: There is no "Java Date format". Use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. For a date-only: YYYY-MM-DD. In Java, `LocalDate.parse( "2020-01-23" )`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert on the client side with the function formatDate(). See more on https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use momentJS that have a number of date conversion, calculation and format functions.

[momentJS](https://momentjs.com/)